# Alphametic as protest

Tags: alphametic

This is my (constructive) way of protesting the new [sandbox for riddles](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5276/19989).
It's a simple alphametic.
You know the rules.
Each letter is a unique digit.
The leading digits cannot be 0 (zero).
If you offer a solution, please add your reasoning.

```
 SAND
+ BOX
-----
NOFUN
```

Since A & B and X & D can be switched and still keep a valid result, this one has 4 solutions.
I will settle for one.

Comment: Disagreeing with your protest about the sandbox but totally agreeing with your way of protesting against it. +1.

Comment: @IAmInPLS. my opinion is this is how all protests should be. everywhere. A constructive way against what you don't agree with. Not a destructive one. Or at least a passive-aggressive approach instead of an aggressive-aggressive one.

Comment: I am all for the sandbox, its a great idea in my mind. Still, i absolutely love this post! nice job. +1

Comment: ***This*** is how protests should be carried out! :)

Comment: @Marius You're lucky: back in the day, Jon Ericson [threatened to suspend](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/1647/5373) anyone who posted meta-commentary about site policy in puzzles ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor. Well...when protesting, one has to take some risks, right? Otherwise it's not a real protest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> S must be 9 and N=1 with O=0. Then D+X must carry (because N+O=U can't be 1), so U=2.
>  Which leaves 3,4,5,6,7,8
>  D+X=11, and A+B=F which must carry and F>2, so A/B are 58,68,78,67, which gives:
> D,X=4,7, A,B,F=5,8,3 (9514+807=10321)
> 68 means both F and D/X are 4, 78 uses 5 twice and 67 uses 3 twice.

Answer (score 18):

> \begin{align}9514\\+\quad807\\\hline10321\end{align}
> As usual, $\text{N}$ must be $1$,
> because $\text{SAND} \le 9999$ and $\text{BOX} \le 999$,
> so $\text{NOFUN}$ cannot be more than $19999$. 
> In fact, it can't be more than $10998$,
> so $\text{O}$ (letter oh) is $0$ (zero). 
> From the ones' column, $\text{D+X=11}$,
> so we carry $1$ into the tens' column and get $\text{U=2}$.
>
> $\text{D}$ and $\text{X}$ can be $3+8$, $4+7$, or $5+6$. 
> From the hundreds' column, $\text{A+B=10+F}$
> (because we need to carry into the thousands' column). 
> Viable options are $5+8=13$, $6+7=13$, $6+8=14$, and $7+8=15$. 
> Of those, all but the first eliminate all possibilities
> for $\text{D}$ and $\text{X}$,
> so we must have $\text{A}$ and $\text{B}$ $=$ $5$ and $8$. 
> That eliminates the first and third options for $\text{D}$ and $\text{X}$,
> leaving us with $4$ and $7$.

> $\text{A}$ and $\text{B}$ $=$ $5$ and $8$
> $\text{D}$ and $\text{X}$ $=$ $4$ and $7$
> $\text{F}=3$
> $\text{N}=1$
> $\text{O}=0$
> $\text{S}=9$
> $\text{U}=2$

Comment: You know the rules for alphametics. A simple solution with no reasoning is not a solution at all. There are a lot of alphametic solvers online. this does not show that you put some effort in it.

Comment: Fast answer and very clear explanation, nice work!

Comment: this is a nice explanation, but a full answer with explanation was added before this one. just +1.

Answer (score 4):

On the first look you get that

> S = 9, otherwise you wouldn't get a 5 digit sum
>  That means that N = 1 and O = 0

So now we get this:

> 9A1D
>  +B0X
>  ------
>  10FU1

Let's dig deeper:

> D + X can't be 1 (zero is already taken), so D + X = 11
>  Now we know that U = 2 (because of D + X = 11)
>  
>  We also see that A + B > 10, that means that F = A + B - 10

The letters and numbers left are:

> A, B, F, D, X and 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.
>  D and X are either 3 and 8, or 4 and 7, or 5 and 6.
>  A + B - 10 must give a number listed above. Trial and error skills:
>
>  We got that A and B are 5 and 8 (using another possibility would take up all valid pairs of numbers for D and X).
>  A + B = 13. F = 3
>
>  The only remaining pair for D and X is 4 and 7.

So, altogether we get:

> 4 solutions. I'll write one here:
>
>  9514
>  +807
>  -------
>  10321