# I am many things

Tags: riddle

<sub>This has been approved on [sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5320/19989)</sub>

I am a place of joy for the kids.
I make the job easier for adults with certain jobs.
I am a tree.

For the kids, I'm made of a lot of small pieces.
For the adults, I don't exist physically.
When I'm a tree, I can grow up to 60m and explode yearly.

That has been my life so far, but lately, I became a rule also.
What am I?

*[Edit - after the question was answered: may contain spoilers]*

> This is part of my protest against sandboxing riddles. Same as [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/41340/19989)

Comment: @AJ. The restrictions changed yesterday: "Currently, in order to post a riddle on the main site, it must be sandboxed here first, and receive a score of +7. This will likely last until better quality standards can be enumerated."

Comment: So, this riddle is also a part of your protest. ;) Anyways nice one +1.

Comment: @AJ.Yep. I will edit the question after the answer is accepted to state this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you :

> The sandbox itself?

I am a place of joy for the kids.

> Kids surely enjoy sandboxes.

I make the job easier for adults with certain jobs.

> For developers [of course](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development))!

I am a tree.

> Well, [indeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hura_crepitans).

For the kids, I'm made of a lot of small pieces.

> Sand comes in grains!

For the adults, I don't exist physically.

> Sandboxes are not a real place for adults.

When I'm a tree, I can grow up to 60m and explode yearly.

> Still refering to the sandbox tree.

That has been my life so far, but lately, I became a rule also.

> [The Riddle Sandbox](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox)!

Comment: This is an other problem with sanboxing riddles. A lot of people can figure out the answer while the question is sanboxed and this becomes a speed race for who posts the answer first.  Nice job. I will accept it when I'm allowed.

Comment: @Marius I can certainly agree with you on this point. To be fair, this one was pretty easy :)

Comment: This was not meant to be too hard. See my edit to the question to understand why. But I guess you already understood my reason.

Comment: @Marius Yes, even if I preferred your [previous form of protest](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41340/alphametic-as-protest) :)

Comment: I promise the next one will be a bit harder and more thought through.

Answer (score 4):

You are a

> Sandbox

**Reasoning:**

I am a place of joy for the kids.

> Children play with sand in the sandbox

I make the job easier for adults with certain jobs.

> Software developers, Sandbox solutions

I am a tree.

> [Hura crepitans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hura_crepitans), the sandbox tree

For the kids, I'm made of a lot of small pieces.

> The sand

For the adults, I don't exist physically.

> It's not a physical object

When I'm a tree, I can grow up to 60m and explode yearly.

> Just some fact about [Hura crepitans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hura_crepitans)

That has been my life so far, but lately, I became a rule also.

> The new rule on PSE :)

Comment: You offered the answer first, but IAmInPLS offered the full reasoning first. So I will accept his answer. Good job.

Comment: Well I assume he can type faster then:D Nevermind :)

Comment: My point exactly: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41507/i-am-many-things/41509?noredirect=1#comment122790_41509