# Alphametic as protest #2

Tags: no-computers, alphametic

**Riddles for all.**
Since [my latest alphametic as protest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/41340/19989) got a good feedback but [my riddle as protest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/41507/19989) did not, I decided to stick to what works and added a new alphametic as  a protest for [the riddle sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5276/19989):

```
 RIDDLE +
 RIDDLE +
 RIDDLE =
 --------
 FORALL
```

Same rules apply.

- each letter is a different digit.
- the leading digits cannot be 0.
- the numbers are in base 10.
- an answer without a reasoning is worth nothing.
- first to answer with a good reasoning gets the checkmark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> L is 4 or 9,  because (3L+[0,1,2])%10 = L and L+[0,10,20]/3=E, L!=E eliminating 0.
>  E+E+E=20+L
>  L = 4, E = 8
>
>  D+D+D+1=A
>  D+D+D+(0 or 2) = R
>  D!=0
>  R+R+R=F
>  R<=3
>
>  Assume R=0
>  D=3
>  A=0
>  R and A can't both be 1, contradiction
>  Assume R=1
>  D=0
>  A=0
>  A and D can't both be 0, contradiction
>  Assume R=2
>  D=7
>  A=2
>  R=3
>  R can't be both 2 and 3, contradiction
>  R=3
>  D=7
>  A=2
>  F=9
>  leaving I=2 and
>  0=5

For a total of

> 317748*3 = 953244

Comment: You can skip the assumption of `R=0` because the leading digit cannot be 0.

Comment: if you explain the first line `L is 4 or 9,` the checkmark is yours.

Answer (score 7):

Immediately, we know that

> $R \in \{1,2,3\}$ since the result is also a 6 digit number.

Also, we know from the ones and tens column that there is a close relationship with $E$ and $L$.  A quick run through of all the possibilities shows that

> the only choice for $E$ that works is $E=8$.  Thus, $L=4$.

Since

> $3 \times L + 2 = 14$, we have a carry over of 1 into the hundreds column.  So $3 \times D + 1 \implies A$.  If $D$ is large, then the carry over into the next column could be 2.  If $D$ is small, then the carry over can be 0. But if $D$ is middling, then the carry over will be 1 again, and we cannot have $A=R$.  Thus, $D$ must be large or small to get a different carry over.  As a consequence, we know that $A$ and $R$ differ by 1.  Since we already know $R\in \{1,2,3\}$, we know that $A \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

Running through possibilities for $D$, the only one that doesn't cause a contradiction with valid values is

> $D=7$.  Thus, $A=2$ and $R=3$.  Therefore, $F=9$.

Also, we know that $I$ must be

> small enough not to cause a carry over.  Thus, $I \in \{0,1\}$. The carry over into the column of $I$s is 2, so if $I=0$, then $O=2$ which is already taken.  Thus, $I=1$ and $O=5$.

Final solution is:

> 317748
>     317748
>     317748
>     ----------
>     953244

Comment: This is much better explained than mine, good work.

Comment: @Sconibulus Thanks!  But I wouldn't say *much* better.  In fact, if I had seen your answer before I added mine, I probably wouldn't have gone through the effort.